# ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript e a Key

Tags: javascript, c#

Boa tarde,

Queria entender como funciona essa Key, tenho uma função no aspx que necessito no code-behind, mas quando a chamo com uma Key estática, colocando `csname = "x";` Ela só é chamada uma vez, mas preciso que seja chamada quantas vezes for necessário, daí tentei colocar o nome como variável e ela nunca é chamada, mesmo sem o `if (!Page.ClientScript.IsStartupScriptRegistered(Page.GetType(), csname))`

Eis o código, este código coloca os itens em um mesmo row de uma gridview, depois ele verifica se colocará o ícone de Expand naquele row, para que o mesmo possa ser expandido quando clicarmos no ícone.

```
protected void gvProduct_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            HyperLink hlProcesso = (HyperLink)e.Row.FindControl("hlProcesso");
            GridView gvRepetidos = (GridView)e.Row.FindControl("gvRepetidos");                
            DataTable dtNew = dtFormsFilhos.Clone();
            bool isRepetido = false;                

            foreach (DataRow row in dtFormsFilhos.Rows)
            {
                if (row["ProcessoFilho"].ToString().Contains(hlProcesso.Text))
                {
                    dtNew.Rows.Add(row.ItemArray);
                    isRepetido = true;                          
                }                    
            }

            if (isRepetido)
            {
                //se coloco o csname como "x" ou "inclui", funciona 1x
                //mas se coloco como está, não funciona. Não entendo como essa key funciona!
                string csname = hlProcesso.Text.ToString();
                string cstext = "IncluiExpand('" + hlProcesso.Text + "')";
                if (!Page.ClientScript.IsStartupScriptRegistered(Page.GetType(), csname))
                    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, this.Page.GetType(), csname, cstext, true);
            }

            gvRepetidos.DataSource = dtNew;
            gvRepetidos.DataBind();                
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Finalmente consegui!

Ao invés de `ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, this.Page.GetType(), csname, cstext, true);`, coloquei `this.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<script type='text/javascript'>"+csText+";</script>"));`

Nem precisa daquele if pra ver se o controle já existe, no meu caso.